# How do I list the names of the files that exist in a folder in a .Net Web Page

Tags: .net, html

I'm newbie to .Net and I have this requirement where I need to list the names of files that exist in a folder in a .Net web page. How do I do it? Please help and guide me

Comment: You decide what language you're going to use, and Google for something like "C# directory list files".  You'll probably find something like this: http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/folder/");
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
```